# Hazelcast: How to use a List as key in hazelcast

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast

When my java service starts, I am fetching a list of String from the database and hence would cache them in hazelcast, key being the list of String and the value (say) 100. There could be multiple lists with different values. The idea is that the next time when my method receives the String as an argument, I should be able to look it up in the hazelcast and return the value.

For example:

```
// These lists are populated from database
List<String> list_1 = new ArrayList<>();
list_1.add("A");
list_1.add("B");

List<String> list_2 = new ArrayList<>();
list_2.add("C");
list_2.add("D");

hazelcast.put("CACHE_KEY_1", list_1, 111);
hazelcast.put("CACHE_KEY_2", list_2, 222);
```

So when my method receives "C" as an argument, the hazelcast should be able to retrieve the value i.e.

```
int value = hazelcast.get("CACHE_KEY_2", "C"); // should return 222
```

I tried looking up this functionality in the documentation but couldn't get any idea about implementing this.

Any pointers would be really helpful.

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put values in the cache for a list of arbitrary strings, and you have two or more different  lists of strings, you need to combine the list name and the string into a single key (called a composed key), for example:

```
 for (String s : list_2) {
   cache.put("CACHE_KEY_2;" + s, 222);
 }
```

So now you can ask the cache, whether the list 2 contained a string 'C' and return the associated integer value:

```
 cache.get("CACHE_KEY_2;C");
```

Instead of using a composed key, you can also use two separate caches. This is the better choice, if the data is very different in nature (different sizes, different access patterns, expiry times, etc.)

BTW: Since a key must be unique it is not a list but a set.

Instead of appending two strings for the composed key, you can also construct an object for this containing the two elements as fields and defining proper equals() and hashCode() methods.

Comment: I see that you are saving a single element by doing list_2.get(1). However I need to save the whole list as key.

Comment: Why? You asked for this as retrieval: `hazelcast.get("CACHE_KEY_2", "C"); // should return 222` There is no list in your retrieval request.

Comment: May be you can edit your question?! How do you need to access the data, after the population is complete? Why you need a cache for it? Who is repopulating the cache an entry is evicted or expired?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Myabe I wasn't clear enough in my question. I am retrieving a list of String from DB which is an expensive operation. Now I save these in hazelcast as Key and a value associated with this list. This value is same for all the elements in the list. Now next time for a given String, I should be able to perform a look up in hazelcast, if this string is present in the key list, then it should return me the value associated with that list.

Comment: Yes, then this is exactly the solution. I updated the answer.

Comment: Hi Rahul, what you are actually looking for is an inverted index. The numbers are document IDs and the strings words in a document. You can use lucene for this.

Comment: How should it behave if both lists have "C"?

Answer (score 1):

Make a new class for the key:

```
class Key {
  private String category;
  private String listItem;
  ...
}
```

To save to hazelcast:

```
for(String listItem: list) {
  hazelcast.put(new Key("CACHE_KEY_2", listItem), 222);
}
```

To fetch:

```
assertEquals(222, hazelcast.get(new Key("CACHE_KEY_2", "C")));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I wouldn't want to iterate over each and every element and save it in the cache. The list might be huge in some cases.I think hazelcast must have something to save the whole list as a key and then using predicates, hazelcast should be able to pull the value for a given string that is present in the key list.